# Max distance between two nodes in a graph is 2, max degree is 3 -- max size?

Tags: graph-theory

I found a solution for eight nodes, here's the adjacency matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&1&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\1&0&0&0&0&0&1&1\\0&1&0&0&0&1&1&0\\0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1\\0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

How could I prove there isn't a larger one?

Comment: The Petersen graph is a larger one satisfying the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a node (first generatrion). It has three neighbours (second generation). Each of these can have two "new" neighbours (third generation), and that's it for diameter $2$. So the maximal number od nodes is certainly $\le 1+3+3\cdot 2=10$. We still need to add two edges per third generation node, and make sure that the distance between two third generation nodes hanging from different second generation nodes is $\le 2$. This can bve solved (try it, and you will the Petersen graph *EnYu* mentions in the commments)